# Kannel not concatenating inbound multipart messages

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, kannel

Kannel doesn't seem to be buffering / concatenating inbound multipart messages.

So if I send a message from my cell phone that is longer than 160 chars (2 messages long) Kannel receives the first message and forwards it to my system, then receives the second part and forwards it to my system independently.

Is there are way to make sure multipart messages are concatenated properly in Kannel?

Answer (score 1):

You can set in **core group**:

```
sms-combine-concatenated-mo = true
```